# How can i store data in both room database and mysql database below is my code

Tags: android, mysql, database, retrofit

Here is my APP retrofit interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("sendorder.php")
Call<order> sendOrder(@Field("name") String name,
@Field("link") String link,
@Field("amount") int amount,
@Field("price") double price);
```

Below is my `try catch` method for storing data into my room database, I also want the data to be stored in mysql database. How can I do that or is that even possible to do?

```
builder.setNegativeButton("CONFIRM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
  dialogInterface.dismiss();
  try {
    mService = Common.getAPI();
    Cart cartItem = new Cart();
    cartItem.name = txt_product_dialog.getText().toString();
    cartItem.amount = Integer.parseInt(number);
    cartItem.price = finalPrice;
    cartItem.link = foodList.get(position).Link;
    Common.cartRepository.insertToCart(cartItem);
    Log.d("KANZEN_DEBUG", new Gson().toJson(cartItem));
    Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Added To Your Order!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      Toast.makeText(context, ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}});

builder.setView(itemView);
builder.show();
```

Comment: why would you need 2 db in your app?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You will need to send the data to your server. You will also need to cache the data when a connection isn't available, then send when a connection becomes available.

Comment: Well we planned to create the user and server side of the app using only room db, but our adviser ask us to make the server side web. But we dont have a single idea how to do it with the room being created. Should we delete the room db and focus on mysql?